# How should I make Zurb Foundation's Top Bar work with iMac 27-inch screen?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, screen-resolution

I'm using Zurb Foundation on a 27" iMac and when the window width is over 1440 px wide, the "mobile menu" is still shown but doesn't work anymore. Under 1440 px, it's shown and is working.

At approx 2100 px, the desktop Top Bar is shown again and works.

On smaller screens, it seems like it works in all sizes (I've tried a 24" Dell screen with 1920x1200 px).

How can I make the Top Bar work on my iMac's 2560x1440 px?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet? Did you customise your grid in any way? It sounds like you've changed something from the default.

Comment: this sounds like a CSS issue that you've made within your code. The make and model of your computer shouldn't have anything to do with it. 

Please post a code snippets or a link to a live site so we can assess this issue.